# Function over vectors collected in a list in R

Tags: r, list, plyr

I have looked long and hard for a solution to the folliwing problem, but I couldn't find it. I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate, and I will delete this question if you direct me to an answer.

I have a `list` (Mylist) where each element holds many different fields. I'm interested in the numeric vector called ´coefficients´. I can thus select coefficients related to the `i'th`instance of the list as

```
Mylist[[i]]$coefficients
```

but how do I get the average of `coefficients` over all `i`? The average is just meant as an example. What I'm generally interested in is how to compute a function over a list where each field of the list holds more than one `data.frame`/`matrix`/`string` etc.

UPDATE: As kindly supplied by Thomas below, here are some fake data for the problem:

```
Mylist <- replicate(10,data.frame(coefficients=rnorm(20),
                              something=rnorm(20)), simplify=FALSE)
```

I have tried looking at `lapply`, but since ´Mylist´ have other fields than `coefficients` I don't see how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to provide more details on the exact structure of your data, but here's a simple example:

```
# some fake data:
mylist <- replicate(10,data.frame(coefficients=rnorm(20),
                                  something=rnorm(20)), simplify=FALSE)
# take the grand mean:
mean(sapply(mylist,function(x) x$coefficients))
```

But perhaps you want the mean for each set of corresponding coefficients across all the list entries, which you could get with something like either of the following (which are identical):

```
colMeans(do.call(rbind,lapply(mylist,function(x) x$coefficients)))
rowMeans(do.call(cbind,lapply(mylist,function(x) x$coefficients)))
```

Which @SimonO101 rightly points out simplifies to:

```
rowMeans(sapply(mylist, function(x) x$coefficients))
```

because `sapply` is just a wrapper for `lapply` that does the simplification for you.

Comment: +1 from me too. I see you added `rowMeans` but you can do it simpler like `rowMeans( sapply( mylist, function(x) x$coefficients ) )`

Comment: Also, `mean(sapply(mylist, \`[[\`, "coefficients"))` and if you use `data.table`, then: `mean(rbindlist(mylist)$coefficients)`

Comment: @Mace why did you accept this answer only to then un-accept it? Especially as you have commented that *Thanks - that's what I needed!* ?

Comment: @SimonO101: Given your argument about the question lacking data and the question not being clear on whether I wanted row means, grand means, or column means, I wanted to update the question with data and make it more general. I have included the data provided by Thomas, and I tried to clarify that the mean/average is just meant as an example of a function. But I can accept this answer again, since I guess it still solves the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the mean for all coefficients across all lists try...

```
mean( unlist( sapply( Mylists , function(x) `[`(x , 'coefficients') ) ) )
```

However, you should clarify what you want because it is unclear if you want...

```
# A mean for each set of coefficients
sapply( Mylists , function(x) mean( x$coefficients ) )

# The mean for each coefficient across all lists
rowMeans( sapply( Mylists , function(x) x$coefficients ) )
```

Comment: I need to remember to just answer these kinds of questions rather than spend time making up fake data... +1

Comment: @Thomas lol - actually it is good to make up fake data because I see I made an error anyways. And you are right, OP needs to provide data - I am unsure if they want mean of all coefficients, or mean of each coefficient across all i (so n means where n = # coefficients)

Comment: Good point, actually. I updated my answer for that possibility.

Comment: I don't think data is need for this simple question. The reason why I didn't specify the dimension to average over is because I don't care. Thanks for the answer! +1

Comment: @Mace strongly disagree. *Every* question is made better with data. Anyway, you got a couple of answers so all is  ok.

Comment: @Mace we had to supply *three* answers for you to get the right one so no, you haven't made a point.

Comment: No, the first one was fine - I just didn't reply in time.